# How to set an image in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to set an image to my flutter screen, so I have been using this `dependency` called `getflutter`. I can set an image by giving a link as below.

```
class _AddNewsState extends State<AddNews> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add News"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Image.file(File(widget.imgPath),fit: BoxFit.cover,) //taking the image passed from `camera_screen.dart`, need to set this to `image:` tag under `GFImageOverlay` below
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: GFImageOverlay(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        image: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/1380')),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have another UI, which takes an image from the camera and passing it to this `AddNews` UI shown above.

What I want is to pass this image I am taking real-time using the camera to this `image:` tag in `GFImageOverlay` class in `getflutter` package.

The image I am taking from the camera is passed to this `AddNews` as below:

This is a part of`camera_screen.dart` where I am calling `AddNews` class and pass the image.

```
void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    try {

      final path =
          join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');
      await controller.takePicture(path);

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => AddNews(
                  imgPath: path,
                )),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
  }
```

In the `AddNews` I want to assign this image to `image:` tag under `GFImageOverlay`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show an image from a file, you have to use the `FileImage` provider:

```dart
GFImageOverlay(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  image: FileImage(File(widget.imgPath)),
)
```